# How can I create and start a parameterized thread in .NET 1.1?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-1.1, nt4

.NET 1.1 lacks `ParameterizedThreadStart` (I have to use 1.1 because it's the last one supporting NT 4.0)

In .NET 2.0, I would simply write:

```
Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SomeThreadProc));
clientThread.Start(someThreadParams);
```

How can I create equivalent .NET 1.1 code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to create a class for the state:

```
class Foo {
  private int bar;
  public Foo(int bar) { // and any other args
      this.bar = bar;
  }    
  public void DoStuff() {
     // ...something involving "bar"
  } 
}
...
Foo foo = new Foo(12);
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(foo.DoStuff));
thread.Start();
```

Comment: I missed the `new ThreadStart(` part before, which does work - but only on 2.0 (1.1 missing anonymous delegates).